# LAN website redirects visitors to their localhost IP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, localhost, mediawiki, lamp

I'm not very good at networking (Still learning) and I have run into a snag that has had me searching the Internet for the past 3 hours now and to no avail.

Here's my scenario:

I have a webserver (LAMP) that has a Wiki on it (Specifically MediaWiki). Whenever ANY computer on my LAN visits the server's local IP (e.g. 192.168.1.2), they are redirected to 127.0.1.1/foo/bar.

And then, when I manually change the IP from 127.0.1.1 back to 192.168.1.2, the site loads the Wiki but there's no CSS or Javascript just HTML.

I tried mod_rewrite but it did nothing for me.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
# domain: mediawiki
# public: /var/www/html/

<VirtualHost *:80>
# Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
ServerAdmin foobar@home
ServerName 192.168.1.2
ServerAlias 192.168.1.2

# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
# Log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /var/www/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do a tail /var/www/log/access.log and look for additional clues. 

Check the .htaccess file in /var/www/html/ for any redirects.

Comment: I don't seem to have a .htaccess file. Hmm.

Comment: Please take a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

Answer (score 0):

Set [`$wgServer`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) in [LocalSettings.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php) properly.